# Number of solutions of $\log(x^{2016}+1)+\log(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2014})=\log2016+2015\log x$

Tags: logarithms, roots

> The number of solutions of the equation
> $$\log(x^{2016}+1)+\log(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2014})=\log2016+2015\log
>  x$$ is equal to:
>
> $a) 1\qquad\qquad b) 2\qquad\qquad c)3\qquad\qquad d) \text{
>  infinite}$

First I simplified the equation,

$$\log\left( (x^{2016}+1)\times\frac{x^{2016}-1}{x^2-1})\right)=\log\left(2016 x^{2015}\right)$$
Hence we have,
$$(x^{2016}+1)\times (x^{2016}-1)=2016(x^2-1)\times x^{2015}$$
From here $x=\pm1$ make both sides zero but only $x=1$ is in the domain of logarithm. But I don't know how to prove $x=1$ is the only solution (in fact the answer key says $(a)$ is correct choice so $x=1$ is the only answer.)

Comment: Off topic query: Are you a JEE aspirant?

Comment: @RiverX15 No I'm not, but found this problem on a book related to JEE.

Comment: You can try expressing the last equation as $y=f(x)=x^{4032}-2016x^{2017}+2016x^{2015}-1$ and apply first and second derivative test to conclude that the graph of $y=f(x), x\in (0,\infty)$ meets (touches, to be precise) the $x$ axis only at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that we only want $x>0$. When $0<x<1$, the two sides cannot be equal (why?). When $x=1$, there is a solution. How do both sides increase after that?